# "Cannot perform reduce with flexible type" in Image Processing

Tags: numpy, python-imaging-library, telegram-bot

I have a problem. The main task is to create a bot in a telegram, which, when a photo is loaded into it, will change the contrast of the image. The main condition is the addition of the so-called black and white dots. Their principle is to search for the lightest point, the darkest and maximum values at these points.Just the code (working, checking) looks something like this (used numpy and PIL).

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open('example1.jpg')
arr = np.asarray(image)

rgbmax = np.max(arr)
rgbmin = np.min(arr)

rgbmax = 240
rgbmin = 15

R, G, B = image.split()

rout = R.point(lambda i: (i - rgbmin) / (rgbmax - rgbmin) * 255)
gout = G.point(lambda i: (i - rgbmin) / (rgbmax - rgbmin) * 255)
bout = B.point(lambda i: (i - rgbmin) / (rgbmax - rgbmin) * 255)

resultimg = Image.merge("RGB", (rout, gout, bout))
resultimg.save("result_img.jpg")
```

This part is required. We must use this method. So, if i use that in my code, i get this error.

```
import telebot
import os
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

TOKEN = 'here token is, just cut it out'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

result_storage_path = 'temp'

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello. I`m bot for processing your images. ')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Please, send me number to continue.')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    cid = message.chat.id
    if message.text.isdigit():
        number = int(message.text)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         'You have sent number = ' + str(number) + '.')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Input isn`t correct. Please, send number.')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_photo(message):
    cid = message.chat.id

    image_name = save_image_from_message(message)
    bot.send_message(cid, 'I save your photo.')
    image_name_new = handle_image(image_name)
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('{0}/{1}'.format(result_storage_path, image_name_new), 'rb'), 'Done!')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Want to try again?')
    cleanup_remove_images(image_name, image_name_new)

def save_image_from_message(message):
    image_id = get_image_id_from_message(message)

    file_path = bot.get_file(image_id).file_path

    image_url = "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{0}/{1}".format(TOKEN, file_path)

    if not os.path.exists(result_storage_path):
        os.makedirs(result_storage_path)

    image_name = "{0}.jpg".format(image_id)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, "{0}/{1}".format(result_storage_path, image_name))
    return image_name


def get_image_id_from_message(message):
    return message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id


def handle_image(image_name):
    content_image = Image.open("{0}/{1}".format(result_storage_path, image_name))
    arr = np.asarray(image_name)

    rgbmax = np.max(arr)
    rgbmin = np.min(arr)

    rgbmax = 240
    rgbmin = 15

    R, G, B = image_name.split()

    rout = R.point(lambda i: (i - rgbmin) / (rgbmax - rgbmin) * 255)
    gout = G.point(lambda i: (i - rgbmin) / (rgbmax - rgbmin) * 255)
    bout = B.point(lambda i: (i - rgbmin) / (rgbmax - rgbmin) * 255)

    result_img_pillow = Image.merge("RGB", (rout, gout, bout))
    image_name_new = "handled_image_" + image_name
    result_img_pillow.save("{0}/{1}".format(result_storage_path, image_name_new))

    return image_name_new

def cleanup_remove_images(image_name, image_name_new):
    os.remove('{0}/{1}'.format(result_storage_path, image_name))
    os.remove('{0}/{1}'.format(result_storage_path, image_name_new))

bot.polling()
```

Error and traceback

```
2020-05-23 13:03:37,571 (util.py:68 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: "TypeError occurred, args=('cannot perform reduce with flexible type',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:/ХНУРЭ/ЦОЗ/imageproc/bot.py", line 42, in handle_photo
    image_name_new = handle_image(image_name)
  File "E:/ХНУРЭ/ЦОЗ/imageproc/bot.py", line 74, in handle_image
    rgbmax = np.max(arr)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in amax
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2668, in amax
    keepdims=keepdims, initial=initial, where=where)
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 90, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/ХНУРЭ/ЦОЗ/imageproc/bot.py", line 119, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 415, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 439, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 111, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:/ХНУРЭ/ЦОЗ/imageproc/bot.py", line 42, in handle_photo
    image_name_new = handle_image(image_name)
  File "E:/ХНУРЭ/ЦОЗ/imageproc/bot.py", line 74, in handle_image
    rgbmax = np.max(arr)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in amax
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2668, in amax
    keepdims=keepdims, initial=initial, where=where)
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 90, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong? The fact is that this is the first task in python, and along the way I'm trying to figure it out. I would be very grateful if you were prompted how to solve this problem, or rather get rid of the error and make it work.

Comment: In the function `handle_image` you do `arr = np.asarray(image_name); np.max(arr)` so you try to find max of string. Did you mean `arr = np.asarray(content_image)`?

Comment: Yeah, but if i use `arr = np.asarray(content_image)` - i had another error: `ERROR - TeleBot: "ValueError occurred, args=('not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)',)`

Comment: Due to the fact that this is new to me, I cannot understand the logic. in part, I understand it, but in general I can’t understand by what principle this works, so I can’t build it so that it works. The fact is that this is part of my coursework and an example was the simplest bot that turned images 180, and it worked as it should. And so, trying to do something similar, only for my task, errors are obtained.

Comment: It is hard to understand why this happens without all traceback information as in your first question. It is better to create separate question with your updates and full traceback error.

Comment: Full traceback error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972578/image-processing-error-not-enough-values-to-unpack

Comment: Examine the `arr` argument given to `max`.  Pay attention to `shape`, but more importantly to `dtype`.  Anything other than a numeric dtype will give problems.  I suspect your `arr` has `object` dtype.