# Image Processing Error, "not enough values to unpack"

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, urllib, telegram-bot

The main problem was described by the [post earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61970403/cannot-perform-reduce-with-flexible-type-in-image-processing). This is a sequel with full code and traceback. I have a certain error while processing photos using the telegram bot. In particular, this is a problem with a change in contrast.
Full code:

```
import telebot
import os
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

TOKEN = 'here token is, just cut it out'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

result_storage_path = 'temp'


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello. I`m bot for processing your images. ')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Please, send me number to continue.')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):
    cid = message.chat.id
    if message.text.isdigit():
        number = int(message.text)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         'You have sent number = ' + str(number) + '.')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Input isn`t correct. Please, send number.')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_photo(message):
    cid = message.chat.id

    image_name = save_image_from_message(message)
    bot.send_message(cid, 'I save your photo.')
    image_name_new = handle_image(image_name)
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, open('{0}/{1}'.format(result_storage_path, image_name_new), 'rb'), 'Done!')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Want to try again?')
    cleanup_remove_images(image_name, image_name_new)


def save_image_from_message(message):
    image_id = get_image_id_from_message(message)

    file_path = bot.get_file(image_id).file_path

    image_url = "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot{0}/{1}".format(TOKEN, file_path)

    if not os.path.exists(result_storage_path):
        os.makedirs(result_storage_path)

    image_name = "{0}.jpg".format(image_id)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_url, "{0}/{1}".format(result_storage_path, image_name))

    return image_name


def get_image_id_from_message(message):
    return message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id


def handle_image(image_name):
    content_image = Image.open("{0}/{1}".format(result_storage_path, image_name))
    arr = np.asarray(content_image)

    rgbmax = np.max(arr)
    rgbmin = np.min(arr)

    rgbmax = 240
    rgbmin = 15

    R, G, B = image_name.split()

    rout = R.point(lambda i: (i - rgbmin) / (rgbmax - rgbmin) * 255)
    gout = G.point(lambda i: (i - rgbmin) / (rgbmax - rgbmin) * 255)
    bout = B.point(lambda i: (i - rgbmin) / (rgbmax - rgbmin) * 255)

    result_img_pillow = Image.merge("RGB", (rout, gout, bout))
    image_name_new = "handled_image_" + image_name
    result_img_pillow.save("{0}/{1}".format(result_storage_path, image_name_new))

    return image_name_new


def cleanup_remove_images(image_name, image_name_new):
    os.remove('{0}/{1}'.format(result_storage_path, image_name))
    os.remove('{0}/{1}'.format(result_storage_path, image_name_new))


bot.polling()
```

And this error and traceback. I will be very grateful if this problem is solved, since python itself is new to me, these are study assignments. This error occurs when a photo is loaded in the bot itself.

```
2020-05-23 16:11:58,514 (util.py:68 WorkerThread1) ERROR - TeleBot: "ValueError occurred, args=('not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:/ХНУРЭ/ЦОЗ/imageproc/bot.py", line 42, in handle_photo
    image_name_new = handle_image(image_name)
  File "E:/ХНУРЭ/ЦОЗ/imageproc/bot.py", line 80, in handle_image
    R, G, B = image_name.split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/ХНУРЭ/ЦОЗ/imageproc/bot.py", line 119, in <module>
    bot.polling()
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 415, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 439, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 111, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 62, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:/ХНУРЭ/ЦОЗ/imageproc/bot.py", line 42, in handle_photo
    image_name_new = handle_image(image_name)
  File "E:/ХНУРЭ/ЦОЗ/imageproc/bot.py", line 80, in handle_image
    R, G, B = image_name.split()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Comment: We don't know the value of `image_name`, but apparently it doesn't contain three space-separated words. Try `print(image_name)` and `print(image_name.split())` as the first thing in the `handle_image()` function, to debug the issue.

Comment: `image_name` seems to just be a string which contains the name of the image. How do you expect to unpack it into 3 variables `R`, `G` and `B`?

Comment: I used that `image_name = save_image_from_message(message)`. It`s from example. If you need, i can show this example with rotate images.

Comment: If I use the part of the code that processes the image separately, in the created project and using only PIL and numpy, then everything works flawlessly, as it should.